# the position of relative clauses

Tags: relative-clauses

Why is this sentence "there were a lot of people at the party who/that hadn't been invited" right grammatically? (It is cited from 'Advanced Grammar in Use, Martin hewings, third edition, p191)

Does it must be fixed "there were a lot of people who/that hadn't been invited at the party"  ?

If we write a sentence that contains a relative clause like as first, 
In some cases I think that we can be coufused for undersanting its meanings.

Comment: I'm flagging this as off-topic ("belongs on ELL"). Hi Sherry, you may not be aware that this EL&U site is for "linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts", whereas your question is probably more suited to our other site [ell.se]. If you have a question for ELL, be sure to read their guidance on [what you can ask](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). :-)

Comment: I do like thinking about the conditions under which a relative clause does not need to immediately follow what it modifies. That is a rather advanced feature of usage that goes beyond what is correct or incorrect.

Comment: duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/221716/when-is-it-correct-to-postpone-an-attributive-clause

Answer (score 3):

> *There were a lot of people at the party that hadn't been invited*

A native listener would parse the relative clause *that hadn't been invited* as modifying the noun phrase *people at the party*. A relative clause doesn't have to come right after the head noun; it follows the noun phrase.

Of course, as you note, it's possible to parse *at the party* as being outside the noun phrase, and that would require a transformation. But that's less likely to occur to a native listener trying to make sense of it.

Comment: If modified as ".....party, who hadn't been invited." it would not confuse. Otherwise, it could be, "There were a lot of people who hadn't been invited, at the party."

Answer (score 0):

Both are OK, no need to "fix".  You can also say

> at the party, there were a lot of people who/that hadn't been invited

and

> there were, at the party, a lot of people who/that hadn't been invited